# Create several tables in a single Json without using JArray?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, mvvm

I'm working on an IMDB-type of program where I am listing people who have a filmography, discography, and similar. So I already made my view in MVVM, and now I am trying to serialize my json to match it. Right now I am gathering up my tables like so:

```
dynamic discography = new JObject(new JProperty("DiscographyVM", jsonDiscography));
dynamic filmography = new JObject(new JProperty("FilmographyVM", jsonFilmography));

dynamic fullJson = new JArray();
fullJson.Add(discography);
fullJson.Add(filmography);
```

This will give me a json looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "Discography" : [
      { 
        "Album" : "MyAlbum",
        "Year" : 2017
      },
      { "Album" : "MySecondAlbum",
        "Year" : 2018
      }
    ],
    "Filmography" : [
      {
        "Film" : "MyFirstMovie",
        "Year" : 2017
      },
      {
        "Film" : "MySecondMovie",
        "Year" : 2018
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is get rid of the outer `[ ]` brackets. So I guess I need to change my `dynamic fullJson` variable to something else, but I can not figure out to what. Any ideas?

UPDATE, I am trying to get this structure:

```
  {
    "Discography" : [
      { 
        "Album" : "MyAlbum",
        "Year" : 2017
      },
      { "Album" : "MySecondAlbum",
        "Year" : 2018
      }
    ],
    "Filmography" : [
      {
        "Film" : "MyFirstMovie",
        "Year" : 2017
      },
      {
        "Film" : "MySecondMovie",
        "Year" : 2018
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are choosing the JObject way and dynamic objects? If not: if you already have all this info in a plain C# class instance you can return it in a Web API and JSON.NET will be called to convert it automatically.

Comment: I collect the data from different sources and populate two `dynamic jsonDiscography = new JArray();` (and Filmography) with all the films/ albums. I want convert this to json to use in my client for futureproofing reasons. I just struggle to deserialize it in my client because of the outer array that I have now.

Comment: The JSON convention is to serialize an array as [ ... ] , source: https://www.json.org/

Comment: Yes I know, I updated the question with what I am trying to do. I am trying to find an alternative to the outer array, or a way to drop it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JObject` instead of `JArray`. Lets see:

```
dynamic discography = new JProperty("Discography", jsonDiscography);
dynamic filmography = new JProperty("Filmography", jsonFilmography);

dynamic fulljson = new JObject { discography, filmography };
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nHpZ7)

Note that I also replace

```
dynamic fullJson = new JObject();
fullJson.Add(discography);
fullJson.Add(filmography);
```

with

```
dynamic fulljson = new JObject { discography, filmography };
```

Comment: Magnificent! I did not think that discography and filmography didn't need to be JObjects. This did exactly what I wanted to do in the easiest way possible.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json is a great library :)

Comment: Ooh, that looks even neater. Cheers again :)